# How to select consecutive elements with the same class?

Tags: html, css

## Problem:

I want to select all the red boxes that are consecutive and change its background color to yellow. But css applied is not working.

## Expected result:

2nd red box should turn to yellow.

## What I have tried:

I have tried to use `+` operator to select elements that are consecutive to each other, but it does not give me expected results.

This is the exact code that I use to select consecutive elements that are 1 level deep:

```css
ul li > div.red + ul li > div.red {
  background: yellow;
}
```

## My code:

Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-wave-1bjmp?file=/main.css

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li>div.red {
  background: red;
}

ul li>div.green {
  background: green;
}

ul li>div.red+ul li>div.red {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="green" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

## Notes:

I am not allowed to make any changes to HTML. This problem should be solved using pure css.

Comment: You can't because the div.red isn't siblings. Can you put the same class at li?

Comment: @Hoch I am not allowed to change HTML as it is being produced by 3rd party library.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's **impossible to solve this problem in pure CSS**. In fact, there is a CSS relational pseudo-class who could help: `:has()`. Using it, you could apply the following selector:

```
ul li:has(div.red) + li > div.red
```

However, **the `:has()` pseudo-class is not supported in any browser**, as you can see in [Can I use website](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas). Therefore, the only solution would be modifying the HTML structure or using JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `target` by it's parent (if it's possible in your original code), then you can do something like this:

```
ul li:nth-of-type(2) > div.red {
  background: yellow;
}
```

**The Code:**

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li>div.red {
  background: red;
}

ul li>div.green {
  background: green;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(2) > div.red {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="green" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

In case you can use **JavaScript**, here is the code:

- Get all `red` elements
- Set `target` (the number of the affected `red`)
- Check all `red` elements, if the `target` match apply the `CSS`.

You can declare a new variable to store the color as well if it's going to change at some point. example:

```
var bgColor = 'yellow';
reds[i].style.background = bgColor;
```

**The Code:**

```js
var reds = document.querySelectorAll('.red');
var target = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < reds.length; i++) {
  if (reds[i] == reds[target-1]){
    reds[i].style.background = 'yellow';
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
}

ul li>div.red {
  background: red;
}

ul li>div.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="green" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="red" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer, but please read notes section in question. I am not allowed to use anything other than css.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice... check now please for a possible method

Comment: Sorry, i did not mention anywhere, but I would say that number of elements may not be always same, so there can be 3 or 4 or any number of consecutive red elements or any number of consecutive green elements.